# SecurityException when using uses-permissions

Tags: android, permissions, android-securityexception

I have two apps : App1 and App2

In App1 specified permission like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.commonname.providers.app2.READ_LOGIN_TOKEN" />
```

In App2 specified peromission like this

```
  <uses-permission android:name="com.commonname.providers.app1.READ_LOGIN_TOKEN" />
```

I have installed applications in order: first App1 then App2.
When I run App1 I received SecurityException, like this:

> ```
>  Writing exception to parcel
> ```
>
> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   com.commonname.providers.App1 uri
>   content://com.commonname.providers.app1/logintoken from pid=5550,
>   uid=10919 requires com.commonname.providers.app1.READ_LOGIN_TOKEN,
>   or grantUriPermission()
>                                                           at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:608)
>                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:483)
>                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:212)
>                                                       at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
>                                                       at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)

Is exists way to request permissions again, while running application?
Or other way to grand access to this permission if application was installed first.

I have read this article https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/PERMS.md#android-50-behavior, and known depending from install order, but maybe exists some way.

Answer (score -3):

It depens on your SDK version, if it higher than 23 you must request permissions runtime.